# need a jquery code example: connect a sortable list to another sortable list located in an iframe

Tags: jquery

I need a simple and clear JQuery code example (using Sortable UI) of how to connect two sortable lists, one of which is located in an iframe.

Please consider the below example. One sortable list (#sortable1) is in the main document. The other sortable list(#sortable2) is in the iframe. I need to be able to drag items from one list to another and vice versa.

```
<ul id="sortable1">
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item2</li>
</ul>

<iframe src="sortable2.html"></iframe>
```

Contents of "sortable2.html"

```
<ul id="sortable2">
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item2</li>
</ul>
```

I'll be very grateful if someone could post a working example. I'm sure it'll be helpful to many other people.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".heriyah").sortable({ 
    handle : '.handle',
    revert: "invalid",
    connectWith: ".heriyah",
    update : function () { 
        var order = $('.heriyah').sortable('serialize'); 
        $("#info").load("admin/sortable.php?"+order); 
    } 
});
```

The `connectwith:` is how you contect with other ordered lists